# With multiple versions of Lua installed is it possible to specify which one luarock to install to?

Tags: lua, conflicting-libraries, luarocks

I have both `Lua 5.1` and `Lua 5.2` installed on Linux. When using `luarocks` to install a package is it possible to pass on option to luarocks that specifies which version of Lua the rock should be installed for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a command line option, but you may have different variants of the LuaRocks command line program available (`luarocks-5.1` and `luarocks-5.2`) *if* you installed LuaRocks for both Lua versions.

You can do so from source using (assuming a Debian/Ubuntu-like `lua5.1` executable):

```
./configure --lua-version=5.1 --lua-suffix=5.1 --versioned-rocks-dir
# make sure that you got the correct Lua executable and include directory
sudo make bootstrap
```

and the same for Lua 5.2.

In case `configure`'s auto-detection does not find the correct executables/directories, the following flags might be of help:

- `--with-lua-bin=DIR` (directory where the Lua executable is installed)
- `--with-lua-include=DIR` (directory where the Lua include files are)
- `--with-lua-lib=DIR` (you probably don't need this one on Linux)

When you have done that, `luarocks-5.1 install some-package` installs the given package for Lua 5.1, and `luarocks-5.2 install some-package` installs that same package for Lua 5.2.

If LuaRocks was installed via a package manager, multiple Lua versions may or may not be supported (e.g. the Debian/Ubuntu package is configured for Lua 5.1 only).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [luaver](https://github.com/DhavalKapil/luaver) for installing, managing and switching between different versions of lua, luarocks.

To install `luaver` run:

> curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dhavalkapil/luaver/master/install.sh -o install.sh && . ./install.sh

Then you can install and use multiple versions of lua as follows:

> luaver install 5.3.1             # Installs lua version 5.3.1
>
> luaver install 5.3.0             # Installs lua version 5.3.0
>
> luaver use 5.3.1                 # Switches to lua version 5.3.1

See https://dhavalkapil.com/luaver/ for more details.